# IAsyncCursor v/s IAsyncCursorSource

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb.driver

During working with ToListAsync() in MongoDB driver 2.0.1, I have observed two different documentations for it.

- IAsyncCursorSourceExtensions
- IAsyncCursorExtensions

What is the difference between these two. The MongoDriver I am using for C# is having IAsyncCursorSource.